# Has every program that is installed a default complier with itself?

Tags: java

I am not native English user and I am sorry for bad English but very interested in programming.
My question is: Has every program that is installed on a specific OS a separate compiler or all programs that are installed on that OS use from a default OS compiler?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is general, like, what happens when you install a desktop app, it depends of a app type and it's installer type.

- There are some, that are distributed with sources and are to be compiled at the installation phase right at your machine. Most often they have anything they need to run the installation successfully, including all necessary compilters. In vast majority of cases you are not supposed to *have something preinstalled* on you OS prior to the program installation.
- But mainly a program is distributed as a bundle of binary artifacts. They are already compiled and packed and are delived in this state. So no, here you are not expected to have *a compiler* on you machine.

Comment: @ lotor You metioned that: There are some ... Do you mean when we download a software actually we downloaded the the source code files and complier file
 and when install the downloaded software during the installation process, actually the complier file complies those source code during the installation process at runtime behaviour and creates machine codes file that whenever we open *.exe file of the installed software, actually these created machine code are run by OS? Did i understand correctly? Please explain more simple for me because I am not English native and beginner if you wan. Thx

Comment: And one more question. I know tht for running a software that is written by java, we need to install jre and jdk on OS. But we have known software like GeoGebra that is written by java. When you downlod it from Internet, you dont need to jre or jdk to be installed and simply by few clicks, the software will be installed and you can run it easily without any preinstalled jre or jdk. How is it possible? I saw many examples of these kind of softwares that are run bu OS without installed pakeages needed to them. Again thanks a loooot.

Comment: 1. you understood it correctly. But these are very rare type of apps, and most of them a enterprise, not for desktops. 2. If can happen that you already have JRE on you machine, it usually is pointed by JAVA_HOME system variable. The other option, very common prior to the recent java release policy change, - the app installer has it's own JRE distributive bundled inside the installer.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is marked with 'java'. Regarding Java

- you must have JRE to *run* a java program. JRE stands for *java runtime environment*, which includes JVM (java virtual machine) and another runtime units. Java feature is to have single JRE to run every java program (let alone versions etc). JRE will *execute* java program.
- if you want to *create* a java program on your computer, you should have have Java SDK (software development kit). It includes compiter and huge bunch af another necessary and useful tools. SDK can turn your java source code to an executable java program.

Comment: thanks but i think you did not understand me. The question is: When you install for example a desktop software like babylon, you see some files in installation folder. Does exist a compiler file between them that compile the program (Babylon) or those files contain machine code that OS compile them and run the program?